# Raise exception on logging.warning

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I want to temporarily make `logging.warning` calls raise an exception, instead of printing and continuing. How can I do this?

```
import logging
logging.warning("Foo") # Should raise exception
logging.info("Bar") # Should not raise exception
```

Comment: I misunderstood you at first time. You should use monkey patching for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you init your logging change warning call

```
def warning(self, message, *args, **kws):
    if self.isEnabledFor(logging.WARNING):
        self._log(logging.WARNING, message, args, **kws)
        raise Exception(message)

logging.Logger.warning = warning
```